# When is the use of bold appropriate in a question?

Tags: discussion, markdown, multiple-questions

I recently had a question edited to remove my bold formatting. I use bold to highlight the key question within my question body.

**Why is this inappropriate use of bold?**

[How can I L2-normalize embeddings for triplet loss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67127138/how-can-i-l2-normalize-embeddings-for-triplet-loss) is the question I am referring to.

Comment: I would suggest that [that person likes to edit, a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4685471/desertnaut?tab=activity&sort=revisions). I've nothing to add to two of the answers below other than that it's borderline to have bolded all that, to have edited, or to roll it back; the two questions could have been one compound sentence without bolding. --- You'd really be **better off** looking at [this search at English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=bold); where this question is probably [answered already](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bwriting-style%5D+bold).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In one of your most recent questions almost all text was bold. Bold is used to highlight something. Highlighting everything kind of beats the point.
Removing it in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67127138/how-can-i-l2-normalize-embeddings-for-triplet-loss) was the good thing to do.

Answer (score 15):

I assume you're talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67127138/revisions). I'd say, given the amount of text, that the emphasis is superfluous. There's no way to read the question body without immediately realizing what your key question is. Whether that's enough reason to remove the bold formatting; let's say that I'd reject a suggested edit which only removes the formatting, but I can understand why that user made that edit.

Answer (score 5):

If you only ask a single question within your posted question, and mark it with a question mark, then there should be no need to use bold to separate your “key question” from any other marked questions in your post.

I think our focused Q&A format benefits greatly when there is only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 0):

When you highlight something like you want to show a **specific** thing that keeps an impression on the viewer.

In a situation like in **resume**, you want to highlight the awards so that the interviewer sees the awards section instead of wasting time.